# what's wrong with this MySQL statement?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT OrgNo, CompanyName FROM ematch WHERE CompanyName = 'SECNET'
```

I try to change the column into another one and it works. Do I need to remove or add the quotes? Also how to add wild characters in the search string?

Comment: We don't know. You forgot to include the error message.

Comment: could be anything. it could be that it doesn't end in a semicolon.

Comment: There is no error message, just empty results!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't answer your first question as I have know idea what the error is you are getting.

As for the second you could use the LIKE Keyword as below

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE aColumn LIKE '%word%'
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Patterns are matched with [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) or [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp).

Comment: So what about that?
SELECT OrgNo, CompanyName FROM ematch WHERE CompanyName LIKE 'A'
It still doesn't return anything!

Comment: That's because `'A'` isn't a pattern. Try `'A%'` instead.